# Методика преподавания русского языка

Tags: преподавание

Помогите охарактеризовать предмет "Русский язык" в педагогическом колледже и в мире науки.

Answer (score 1):

Предмет "Русский язык" - это система языковых средств в виде письменной и устной речи, изучающая все уровни языка: фонетику, лексику, морфологию, словообразование, синтаксис, пунктуацию, орфоэпию и т. д.